# reading values from config.ini in PHP

Tags: php, config

You would think I should have found this on Google, but I couldn't.

config.ini

```
 [ENVIRONMENT]
env = prod
js_path = js/
css_path = css/
;host= www.xxxxxxxx.com
    host=http://localhost:8080/home  
test = 0
```

I need to read the value of host here:

```
<?php
header('Location: ?????????????????');
echo 'Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.';
}
?>
```

Anyone knows?

Comment: Check [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

Comment: really? Google 'php read ini file', first link...

Comment: I think your are just to lazy to use google: https://www.google.com/search?q=reading%20values%20from%20config.ini%20in%20PHP. Just googled your heading.

Comment: If you didn't realize, posting a question on SO takes more time n effort than Googling (especially if its the first link on Google)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple. Use the built-in function [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file):

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file('../containing-folder/config.ini');
$host = $ini_array['host'];
```

And, to redirect the user, you can do:

```
if (isset($host) && filter_var($host, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo 'Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.';
    header("Location: $host");
    exit();
}
```

This will also make sure that `$host` is a valid URL.

Comment: It cant find config.ini. I guess I'll need to give absolute URL there.

Comment: @Adi: It should work. What does `var_dump(file_exists('path-to-config.ini-here'));` output?

Comment: boolean false. How??!! The file exists right there! Source Folder/Config/config.ini

Comment: @Adi: Try with an absolute path, then.

Comment: I can access it with http://localhost:8080/config/config.ini. Yes I am on Windows. Using XAMPP (if that's relevant).

Comment: could this have something to do with the action attribute for the form that I am trying to submit?
<form action="view/templates/send_email.php"> and "send_email.php" is where I have the code for redirecting.

Comment: @Adi: I'm not sure what's your directory structure is. Can you post the output of `echo dirname(__FILE__);`? (add this in `send_email.php`)

Comment: It gives me my local directory - G:\MyFolder\Working Folder \view\templates